# Mitochondria - ETC

Tags: mitochondria

I read somewhere that the Malate aspartate shuttle transfers the electrons to complex 1 in the ETC while Glycerol phosphate
shuttle uses complex 2. Does anyone know if this is true? Also a lot of textbooks state that complex 2 can bypass complex 2. Does anyone know if this is true? I have seen this statement in the book Biochemistry by Voet and Voet.

Comment: Hello! thank you for the answer. But do you know if it is possible for these two complexes to bypass each other?

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if you have any references for this above mentioned bypassing.